# "dateformat" independent form of datetime string in query for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am unfamiliar with SQL Server, and would like to do some ad-hoc searches in a dockerized legacy SQL Server database using SQL Server Management Studio where one of the fields is a datetime and I would like to use the BETWEEN operator to extract for a given period.

So something like

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
select card, sum(amount) as sum, count(*) as count
  FROM ... where cardused between '01-03-2021' and '03-03-2021' group by card
```

Now my problem is that this is interpreted as MDY dates and not DMY dates (which is what we use here).  Server is TZ'ed to Europe/Copenhagen.  My Windows 10 speaks Danish.  If I run `set dateformat dmy;` first it is interpreted as expected.

**Is there a documented format that always interprets correctly when used in a query string regardless of server settings?**

Based on earlier work with Excel this might be something like

```
'2021-03-01 15:36'
```

to get this in my local timezone.  Server and client will both run in the same timezone eventually - would this be an issue?

Comment: In addition to an ISO 8601 string format, note that a `BETWEEN` will not provide the desired results when the datetime value includes a time other than midnight. Assuming you want all the values within the specified date range in your question, I suggest an inclusive start and exclusive end range, like `cardused >= '20210301' AND cardused < '20210304'`.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thank you. I am not very familiar with SQL Server. Will this work with hours and minutes as well?

Comment: Yes, the inclusive start/exclusive end technique works with a time component too. Be aware that the legacy datetime type (not datetime2) is only accurate to 1/300 fractional seconds so some fractional second values will get rounded (e.g. '2021-01-01T23:59:59.999' is rounded to '2021-01-02T00:00:00.000').

Comment: I suggest you read Tibor's discussion of the [datetime datatype](https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes).

Comment: @DanGuzman Just to clarify:  The thing you are pointing out with BETWEEN is that if it is  used with date-only values then it does not include events on that day but after midnight.  If the values include a time-of-day as well, then that is not a concern?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, to state it another way, if values include time-of-day, `BETWEEN` will include rows exactly midnight on the end date but not later on the same day. So the query in your question will include '03-03-2021T00:00:00' but not '03-03-2021T01:00:00'. When the values do not include a time of day (i.e. a `date` data type or `datetime` with time-of-day always midnight), the rows on the end date will be included because they match the end date exactly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use datetime strings in ISO 8601 format:

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]
YYYYMMDD[ hh:mm:ss[.mmm]]
```

> To use the ISO 8601 format, you must specify each element in the
> format, including the T, the colons (:), and the period (.) that are
> shown in the format.
>
> The brackets indicate that the fraction of second component is
> optional. The time component is specified in the 24-hour format.
>
> The T indicates the start of the time part of the datetime value.
>
> The advantage in using the ISO 8601 format is that **it is an
> international standard with unambiguous specification. Also, this
> format isn't affected by the SET DATEFORMAT or SET LANGUAGE setting.**

[More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: XKCD has a rant about this: https://xkcd.com/1179/

Comment: I didn't know that MS nowadays refers to the "unseparated" also as "ISO 8601" format. You learn something every day. A tiny addition: The format with separators space instead of without that T (as in YYYY-MM-DD [hh:mm:ss[mmm]] is also language neutral, but only when converted to the *new* datetime types. If you even suspect you'll  deal with the old types, you'll end up with those conversions being language dependent.